Atom pattern matching in an overloaded function head
Brief description
I'm making an Air Pollution Monitor system, where you can add various stations, readings, and then read this saved data afterwards.
Problem
I have an issue while trying to match various atoms within a single function. My code is:
handleRequest(add_station, {Name, Coordinates}, Monitor) ->
  {add_station(Name, Coordinates, Monitor), ok}.

handleRequest(get_station, {Station}, Monitor) ->
  {StationData, _} = get_station(Station, Monitor),
  {Monitor, StationData}.

But it fails to compile under this error: function handleRequest/3 already defined
Usage
I want to call this function like this:
serverLoop(Monitor) ->
  receive
    {request, Pid, {Action, Payload}} ->
      UpdatedMonitorOrError = handleRequest(Action, Payload, Monitor),
      if
        is_tuple(UpdatedMonitorOrError) ->
          % is a tuple like {error, Message} only in case of error occured, is a list otherwise
          Pid ! {reply, UpdatedMonitorOrError},
          serverLoop(Monitor);
        true ->
          % UpdatedMonitorOrError is a valid Monitor which could be treated as the next state
          Pid ! {reply, Response},
          serverLoop(UpdatedMonitorOrError)
      end
    end.

Where Action is a certain atom. I want to avoid making multiple receive pattern matching clauses as most of the code would be repeated.
Note that Payload could be a tuple consisted of various number of elements based on the Action atom and this atom should determine the behavior of handleRequest function. Additionally, Response could be a single atom or a data returned from a function.
Other tries
What I have also tried, to no avail:
handleRequest(add_station, Payload, Monitor) ->
  {Name, Coordinates} = Payload,
  {add_station(Name, Coordinates, Monitor), ok}.

handleRequest(get_station, Payload, Monitor) ->
  {Station} = Payload,
  {StationData, _} = get_station(Station, Monitor),
  {Monitor, StationData}.

What finally worked
handleRequest(Action, Payload, Monitor) ->
  case Action of
    add_station ->
      {Name, Coordinates} = Payload,
      {add_station(Name, Coordinates, Monitor), ok};
    get_station ->
      {Station} = Payload,
      {StationData, _} = get_station(Station, Monitor),
      {Monitor, StationData}
  end.

Two questions

Why is this atom pattern matching not working as intended?
Is this Erlang-way of solving this problem? Is there a better approach? Note that an action could have invalid Payload and then it should return an error and don't modify stored data.


Please provide minimal reproducible example.

Also, please ask one question per post.

The cause of error is that you used . dot instead of ; semicolon between function clauses. See https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions#function-declaration-syntax

In Erlang, clauses of the same function must be separated by a semicolon instead of a dot:
handleRequest(add_station, {Name, Coordinates}, Monitor) ->
  {add_station(Name, Coordinates, Monitor), ok};
                                           %%  ↑ note ";" instead of "."
handleRequest(get_station, {Station}, Monitor) ->
  {StationData, _} = get_station(Station, Monitor),
  {Monitor, StationData}.

